Scheduled Cloud Flow - How to send an email to a list of people in SharePoint List Person column?
I have a SharePoint list that has these columns:
Step (integer starts from 1)
Document (lookup column from a SharePoint Library)
Assigned User (Person/Group Column that Allow Multiple Selections).
Example of the list:
 Step   Document   Assigned User
 1      Doc1       Smith, John Smith, Mary
 2      Doc1       Smith, Anne

I posted a similar question, but doing it from the Canvas app.
But, this time, for another process, I need to do it in Scheduled Cloud Flow.
In Scheduled Cloud Flow, how can I send an email to the list of users for Document Doc1,Step 1 ie. send an email to Smith, John and Smith, Mary ?
I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Z-xtKcRnyE, but that process is triggered when an item is added to a SharePoint list.
In my case, I need to "Get Items" from the SharePoint List and set Filter Query to Document eq 'Doc1' and Step eq 1.
In the next steps like Compose, as soon as I select anything from "Get Items" like "Assigned User", it puts the Compose inside "Apply to each", and I can't move it outside the "Apply to each".
When I run it, it didn't send me any email. Thank you.


----Update with resolution----
I found my issue.
I failed to mention that Document is a lookup column.
So, in "Get Items", i need to set the filter query to this:
Document/Title eq 'Doc1' and Step eq 2


check that your default view contains the field Assigned user

Where can I find Default view ?

append your mail in a string
@{outputs('Get_items')?['body/value']}
Initialiaze your variable who will contains your mails

apply to each value
@{items('Apply_to_each')?['AssignedTo/Email']};
append to your variable


Thank you. I updated my original post with your suggestion, but it still doesn't send email, even though i hard coded the email to my email (I just want to see if the flow go thru until the email). I probably set the "Select" and "Join" values incorrectly ?

Is there any error on send mail action? action send mail not triggered? did you check your spams in outlook?

I found my issue. I updated my original post with the resolution. Thank you all for your help
